# One way communication only

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have connected my netgear r7000 to my existing home network as a second router and assigned the ip 192.168.2.1 to it while the main router has 192.168.1.1

Everything works fine, wifi, eth cables, etc.. The problem is : I have a server with ip 192.168.1.100 (connected via cable to the 192.168.1.1 router) and I can connect to it via SSH from another machine that is connected to the 192.168.2.1 router (with ip 192.168.2.115) but not the other way around. The other way around does not allow me to even ping the gateway 192.168.2.1.

From 192.168.1.100 I can ping 192.168.1.1 (main router) but not 192.168.2.1 (dd-wrt router).

On the 192.168.1.100 machine there is no firewall, I tried to narrow down and locate the issue by connecting another laptop from the exact same eth cable of the 192.168.1.100 machine, same issue : Cannot ping 192.168.2.1.

I than connect the same laptop physically to the 192.168.1.1 router still cannot ping the 192.168.2.1, thats why I presume that 99% of that the issue is somewhere related to the dd-wrt router.

To simplify :

```
192.168.1.100 ping -> 192.168.1.1 OK
192.168.1.100 ping -> 192.168.2.1 No Response
192.168.1.1 ping -> 192.168.2.1 No Reponse

192.168.2.115 ping -> 192.168.1.100 OK
192.168.1.100 ping -> 192.168.2.115 No Response

192.168.2.115 SSH -> 192.168.1.100 OK
192.168.1.100 SSH -> 192.168.2.115 Connection timeout

192.168.1.1 = Main router
192.168.2.1 = dd-wrt router
192.168.2.115 = Machine 1
192.168.1.100 = Machine 2
```

I already tried to factory reset the 192.168.1.1 router, to change the netgear router range from 192.168.2.1 to 10.0.0.1, same issue :(

Also tried to tcpdump the eth interface while I try to ping to see if there is some message, nothing found.

The message I get from the ping itself (from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.2.1) is :

```
    [root@server_centos7 ~]$ ping 192.168.2.1
    PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 213.XXX.XXX.234 icmp_seq=76 Packet filtered
    From 213.XXX.XXX.234 icmp_seq=142 Packet filtered
```

Where is this packet filtered coming from? The IP 213.XXX.XXX.234 is unknown to me. On the dd-wrt the firewall is disabled and I have no clue where else I can check. Is there perhaps a conf issue somewhere? Can somebody help me to figure this out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake. People hook up a second router and leave it in NAT gateway mode as if it's their head-of-network router, thus it splits their downstream half of their home LAN off from their upstream half of their home LAN, *just like it was designed to do*.

The solution is to make your downstream "router" just act like a transparent bridge instead of a NAT gateway router. You want it to be like a plain bridging Wi-Fi AP with integrated Ethernet switch, not act as a "router" at all.

- On some devices such as AirPort Base Stations, you can turn off the NAT and DHCP Server services and the WAN port will become just another LAN port.
- On other devices, there's no way to disable NAT, so you just have to disable the DHCP Server service, and stop using the WAN port. Plug one of the downstream router's LAN ports into one of the upstream router's LAN ports. Give the LAN side of the downstream router an IP address that's valid (but not currently in use) on the LAN side of the upstream router (so, something in the 192.168.1.x range in your case). If the downstream router isn't serving DHCP, it can't tell anybody about its NAT service, so its NAT service is rendered harmless. Now the upstream router will act as the NAT gateway and DHCP server for the entire network, regardless of which box the client devices are connected to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have searched on the dd-wrt wiki and I found various ways to connect a router to another router : Access Point / Switch, Repeater / Repeater Bridge, Client / Client Bridge,  WDS and OLSR. Which one do I have to follow exactly? I have just tried the "Repeater Bridged Setup" as here https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/images/9/9b/Repeater_Bridge.jpg but when I applied the settings the whole network went down, I had to reset the router to factory default to bring internet back. I am a noob, I know, and I really hate this stuff as they are unclear and confusing :(

Comment: @rf2632 You want their Access Point instructions. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point

Comment: I am afraid that this is not the right solution for different reasons: As soon as DHCP is off, the static DNS will be off too and I need that for the VPN settings. Also, without DHCP the router will not be able to assign any IP to the clients and he will stuck at "Obtaining IP address...". The upstream router is quite far from the downstream router and the clients will not be able to get enough wifi signal coming from the upstream router. The 2 routers are connected LAN to WAN via ethernet through a switch. This is actually how my setup looks like https://s27.postimg.org/57s2p47cz/Network.jpg

Comment: @rf2632 If you configure your downstream router as a simple access point, it's just a switch. A switch that happens to have some wireless ports. So everything in your home will get DHCP leases from your main router (the one on the first floor, at 192.168.1.1), and you can configure static DNS settings on that box. You won't have range issues because at the 802.11 layer, your wireless clients will still connect to the nearest wireless AP. It's just that their DHCP requests will get forwarded from wireless to wired to the main router.

Comment: @rf2632 You might want to update your Question to be clear exactly what your VPN requirements are. If you want your secondary router to act as a VPN router, connecting a chunk of your home LAN to some remote network via a VPN tunnel, then it might be hard to have it do that and yet still let the rest of your home devices reach those VPN-protected devices.

Comment: Actually I would like to have the whole network going through a VPN but the main router cannot be replaced or flashed with another firmware. The VPN settings are from here https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/dd-wrt-openvpn as I have a subscription with them. I will try, hopefully today, to follow the AP instructions and see if it works.

Comment: The solution was very simple!! I had to ssh into 192.168.2.1 router and run the following command : iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT. After saving I can now communicate with the .2.1 to the .1.1 segment and vice versa :)